# Cannot find module error - css modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, css-modules

The line `import * as Styles from './ButtonStyle.css';` is throwing the error `[ts] Cannot find module './ButtonStyle.css'`

My component:

```
require('./ButtonStyle.css');

import * as React from 'react';
import * as Styles from './ButtonStyle.css';

export interface IState{
    type: string;
    className: string;
    caption: string;
}

export class Button extends React.Component<{}, {}>{
    render(){
        return(
            <button 
                type="button" 
                className="btn btn-primary"
            >Work In Progress</button>
        );
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "src",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "4.6.0",
    "@types/react": "15.0.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.1",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "3.0.3",
    "@types/react-router": "4.0.12",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "4.0.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack-react": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-router-dom": "4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-virtualized-select": "^3.0.2",
    "react-virtualized-select": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        entry: { 'main': './ClientApp/boot.tsx' },
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader?minimize' }) },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CheckerPlugin(),
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css')
        ])
    }];
};
```

Comment: Where is your `ButtonStyles.css` file situated in relation to your index?

Comment: it's in the same folder as my `Button.tsx` file.